# TADOQuery.Open executes a statement but only once

Tags: database, delphi, insert, ado

I use this code to copy row from Table1 to Table2, but it gives me

> Command Text does not return a result set

```
 ADOQuery1.Close;
 ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
 ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('insert into Table1');
 ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('select Field1 ,Field2 from Table2');
 ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('where ArtNo= 1');
 ADOQuery1.Open;
 ADOQuery1.Refresh ;
```

If I don't use

```
 ADOQuery1.Open;
```

it gives me

> ADOQuery1: Cannot perform this operation on a closed dataset.

It copies what I want but only once. How to copy many times? Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

For scripts that do not open a cursor (like insert, update or exec ones) use the ExecSQL Method of TADOQuery.

It returns a Integer representing the number of affected rows by your query.

```
ADOQuery1.Close;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('insert into Table1');
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('select Field1 ,Field2 from Table2');
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('where ArtNo= 1');
NumRows := ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
ShowMessageFmt('Affected rows on Table2: %d', [NumRows]);
```